# How to center bootstrap checkbox form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[I need to center this checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kQaC.png)
Could anybody help me center this checkboxes? i've try so many things already.

here's my code:

```
  <div class="row checkbox-row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Adult News</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row checkbox-row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Youth News</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/20/

since bootstrap rows are in a 12 column grid, I checkboxes to span 2 columns each, and moved the 4 columns to the right by 4.

```
<div class="row checkbox-row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-4">
    <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" value="">Adult News</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row checkbox-row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <div class="checkbox-inline">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" value="">Youth News</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used your code, gave the checkboxes some width with css and they got placed where I wanted them!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <div class="row checkbox-row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="checkbox-inline" style="text-align:center;">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Adult News</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row checkbox-row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="checkbox-inline" style="text-align:center;">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Youth News</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution but works if you change the col-sm as per your page.

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Adult News</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row checkbox-row">
                <div>
                  <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="">Youth News</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```